# GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace Not working?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

### Summary

This happened since May 20th's night (Pacific Time). Initially, I thought it was Google Cloud Storage failure. It seems now that they supported my way of storing data before.  But somehow, after May 20th, that API does not work the same way as before.

### How did I call

```
  GcsFileOptions fileOptions = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/png").acl("public-read").build();
  GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(fileBucket, objectName); // fileBucket="test", objectName="/code/my/yeuei"
  GcsService service = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
  GcsOutputChannel oc = service.createOrReplace(filename,fileOptions); //error happens here.
```

### Error

> Google Cloud Storage API gives error when the object is not existing.
>       GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace method

I am creating a new object.

```
   E 10:03:00.643 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.NonRetriableException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:68)
```

This line seems causing the error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.oauth.URLFetchUtils$HTTPRequestInfo.<init>(URLFetchUtils.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.oauth.OauthRawGcsService.beginObjectCreation(OauthRawGcsService.java:184)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.call(GcsServiceImpl.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.call(GcsServiceImpl.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:108)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized in time.

Comment: Are you getting an HTTP error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: I did not see an HTTP error. I got this -Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.oauth.URLFetchUtils$HTTPRequestInfo.<init>(URLFetchUtils.java:80)

Comment: That sounds like a client-side error. Did anything change in your code? Can you post your relevant code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing on the [status page](https://code.google.com/status/appengine).  You might wish to check it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is resolved. I am still not sure how it is introduced in the first place.

Here is what happens -
There is a class URLFetchUtils in App Engine GCS Client library, when it initiates, it did not check if payload is null, that creates the NullPointer exception. Today, GCS Java Client Library has an update fixed this issue, so if you use the latest version (app engine GCS 0.3.12), this error will go away. Interestingly, I have no idea how it worked before :) ... But anyway, I am glad that my app is working again - after about 24 hours down.